# Drupal views custom template array issue

Tags: views

I have made a view named **services** which fetches the fields of content type **services**, fields name : services_text and services_image.
I have made a custom tpl named *views-view--services.tpl.php* with my own structure and want to access fields like `$row['services_text']` in for each, but it comes out as undefined index, as i can figure it out, by using `var_dump`, that this tpl is not getting any row rather plain html string for output so I even tried with views-view-unformatted.tpl.php, but still no use.

Kindly help.

Comment: create file using "Row style output" instead of from "Style output"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use views-view-fields--.tpl.php and render the field with your custom markup

For example:

```
<div class="product-item">
    <div class="row clearfix">
      <div class="product-image"><?php print $fields['field_images']->content; ?></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row clearfix text-center">
      <div class="product-attributes"><?php print $fields['title']->content; ?></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row clearfix text-center">
      <div class="product-attributes"><?php print $fields['title_1']->content; ?></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row clearfix  text-center">
      <div class="product-attributes price"><?php print $fields['another_field']->content; ?></div>
    </div>
</div>
```